# Querying referenced mongoDB collection with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoDB document schema for favourite products is currently structured below:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  addedBy: ObjectId,
  product: ObjectId
}
```

I am trying to query the product collection referenced in the favoritesProducts collection using search filtering functionality but I have been unable to achieve this. Below is how I'm currently querying the DB to filter the products:

```
const getFavoriteProducts = asyncHandler(
  async (req, res) => {
    const addedBy = req.user._id;

    const { page, limit, searchTerm } = req.query;

    const currentPage = page ? page : 1;
    const pageLimit = limit ? limit : 10;

    const query = {
      addedBy,
    };

    if (searchTerm) {
      const searchTermArray = searchTerm.match(/"[^"]*"|\S+/g) || [];
      
      query["$and"] = searchTermArray.map((word) => {
        return {
          $or: [
            { "product.productName": { $regex: word, $options: "i" } },
            { "product.brandName": { $regex: word, $options: "i" } },
            { "product.category": { $regex: word, $options: "i" } },
            { "product.subCategory": { $regex: word, $options: "i" } },
          ],
        };
      });
    }

    const favoriteProducts = await FavoriteProducts.find(query)
      .skip((Number(currentPage) - 1) * pageLimit)
      .limit(pageLimit)
      .populate("product")
      .exec();

    const total = await FavoriteProducts.countDocuments(query)
      .exec();

    if (!favoriteProducts) {
      return res.status(400).json("No favorite products found");
    }

    res.status(200).json(
      successHandlers({
        results: favoriteProducts,
        total,
      })
    );
  }
);
```

Currently, when I test the api endpoint by adding the searchTerm to the query params, I get an empty array as the returned value of the results and zero(0) as the value of the total. What could possibly be wrong with this query? I am very new to backend and database querying so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `req.user._id` is a string, `addedBy` is an ObjectId, therefore no match.  Explicitly cast the string to an ObjectId in order to query.

Comment: Actually, req.user._id an ObjectId and not explicitly a string. I logged the value and it is an ObjectId that gets returned. Also, the problem is not with the addedBy but rather from the product. The properties I'm querying against are all properties of the product schema but this doesn't work because the product is saved as a ref in this collection.

Comment: Should check that with `typeof` to be sure.  Having `req` contain a non-JSON type would be a neat trick